# Word to describe one who loves friends more than family

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word to describe someone who loves his friends more than his family?

For example, my brother is a sort of person who seems to be only interested in his friends (not me nor the rest of the family). I'm looking for any words and/or idioms to describe my brother.

Comment: Extrafamilial could work, as in interest or focus outside the family.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP's brother is exhibiting [extrafamilial orientation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=extrafamilial&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22extrafamilial%20orientation%22&oq=%22extrafamilial%20orientation%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...9399.13759.3.14238.9.9.0.0.0.0.195.788.7j2.9.0...0.0.ulTi-TStx8w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fcf837133a4217b6&biw=1157&bih=867) - normal behaviour for young adults of both sexes as they approach the age at which they will leave the parental "nest".

Comment: O.P.'s age is not on profile; how do we know he and his brother are "young adults"? Moreover, that phrase seems more of a technical term in behavioral sciences than something I'd say at the Thanksgiving table (per your link: _However, the husband is not as tied to the home by the child as is his wife, and his socialization history and occupational concerns encourage an extrafamilial orientation_) which is fine, if that's what the OP wants, but: "Why isn't Bob here? He's missed Thanksgiving two years in a row!" "Oh, you know Bob and his extrafamilial orientation!" seems overly technical to me.

Comment: @J.R.: We don't have a single commonplace word for *"not [no longer] family-oriented"* - depending on how Bob's mommy feels about the situation, it's either *"Oh Bob's out with them fine folks up on the hill"*, or *"He out wit dem lowlifes agin"*.

Comment: I like both of those suggestions more than _extrafamilial orientation_ :^)

Answer (score 3):

When people refer to someone as being *social* (at least in the U.S.), they rarely mean that the person is spending time with his or her family. "*Oh, he's so social.*" means that he is in the habit of spending time away from home (and family) and with friends. I think if it's noticeable enough to be commented on, it's probably not a compliment.

(I would say, however, this seems to be normal behavior for teenagers. [I have two.])

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be hard to find a word that relates exclusively to the family, outside of rather technical terms.  With that in mind, I'd maybe try applying more general purpose words, and put them into context with the rest of the sentence.  For example, you could use words like ***insular*** or ***detached***.

*Insular* is an adjective that means: *remote, detached, or aloof; isolated or separated*.
Wiktionary defines *insular* as: *Having an inward-looking, standoffish, or withdrawn manner*.

*Detached* is defined as: *not feeling involved with someone or something in a close or emotional way.*

Again, these are *not* words that completely convey what you want, not as a single word.  When *insular* is used to describe a person, it usually refers to someone who is a loner in general, not just toward family members.  *Detached* can mean someone is withdrawn, and might imply a vacant sullenness.  However, one might still use these words to apply to a family member who would prefer to stay with friends, and avoid the rest of the clan:

> *My brother is very insular toward his family*.
>   *My brother stays rather detached from the family.*

Comment: -1 *insular* is a "non-specific" attribute - isolated from **everything**, not from close family in particular.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ...Hence my clarification that the word could only be used with a qualifying phrase – with emphasis in italics, even!

Comment: I think in this context, once you accept you *have* to explicitly name things, *detached* or *withdrawn* would be more common. Even *insulated* or *isolated* are plausible - at least you can actually adopt such stances, not having been like that before. But an island is an island - it's in its *nature* to be so, not just some new behaviour it exhibits.

Comment: I like *detached* - that's an improvement on my answer for sure. Would you mind if I modified my answer to include *detached*?

Comment: You don't need my approval. I just don't think it's normal to speak of someone being *insular **from** something* - but if you change it to *detached from his family*, I'll cancel my downvote.

Comment: @Fumble: To be honest, I didn't think _insular_ was all that good a fit, either, but the question had sat for five hours with only _extrafamilial_ and _social_ being offered.  As for it not being a "normal" use of the word, I agree with that, too ~ but, for that matter, _extrafamilial_ isn't exactly an everyday word, either.  _Insular_ may have been untenable, but at least it led to a conversation which gave us _detached_, which I like quite a bit, and have now included in my response.